# Script to Show/Hide Content Requires Two Clicks to Execute First Time

Tags: javascript

We're using the following code to show/hide content when an image is clicked:

```
  function toggle(image,list)
  {
    var listElementStyle=document.getElementById(list).style;
    if (listElementStyle.display=="none")
    {
      listElementStyle.display="block";
      document.getElementById(image).src="images/down.png";
      document.getElementById(image).alt="Close list";
    }
    else
    {
      listElementStyle.display="none";
      document.getElementById(image).src="images/up.png";
      document.getElementById(image).alt="Open list";
    }
  }
```

The function is invoked like this:

```
<p>
<img src="images/up.png" alt="Open List" id="img39384" onClick="toggle('img39384','ul39384');">Agriculture
<ul id="ul39384" class="catList">
<li>
<a href="databases.jsp?cat=39386">Agriculture - Most Useful</a>
</li>
</ul>
</p>
```

The first time an "up.png" is clicked, it takes two distinct click to fire-off the script and show/hide content.  After that first two-click invocation, a single click will fire the script.  This behavior holds true in all browsers--IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Chrome.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Any html element (say a div) positioned on top or partially on top of your image could cause this behavior if it has any sort of listener to an event as well.. use a tool like a developer tool bar to check if you can find any element positioning in front of your image...

Answer (score 2):

Your `<ul>` element is probably inheriting `display: none` from a CSS rule.

However, because the element's style wasn't explicitly set (inline), `elem.style.display` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`element.style` only contains style properties that are defined in the element's style *attribute* (i.e., `style=""`) and not style properties inherited from `<style>` blocks or external CSS files.

[Read here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) for an abstracted way to retrieve style information.

Answer (score 1):

The display value of the element may not be explicitly "none" to start off with.  Try this:

```
  function toggle(image,list)
  {
    var listElementStyle=document.getElementById(list).style;
    if (!listElementStyle.display || listElementStyle.display=="none")
    {
      listElementStyle.display="block";
      document.getElementById(image).src="images/down.png";
      document.getElementById(image).alt="Close list";
    }
    else
    {
      listElementStyle.display="none";
      document.getElementById(image).src="images/up.png";
      document.getElementById(image).alt="Open list";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your img a

```
style="display: block;"
```

attribute when the page loads initially.